# How Can I Install Memcached on Debian Jessie with PHP 7.1.1

Tags: php7, php-memcached

The command `apt-get install php-memcached` will be installing `php7.0`.

Is there any way to install `memcahed` extension with `php7.1`?

Comment: Did you install PHP 7.1 via `apt-get` or something different?

Comment: apt-get it was..

Comment: Debian Jessie doesn't have PHP 7.1 packages. https://wiki.debian.org/PHP#Available_versions Did you add an additional repository like https://www.colinodell.com/blog/2016-12/installing-php-7-1 suggests?

Comment: the sid repository

Comment: Then the package name would probably be something like `php7.1-memcached`. If that doesn't exist, you may need to use PECL. http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.installation.php

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile php extension from source . IIRC there is no apt-get method is available yet.

install required libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev libmsgpack-dev libmsgpackc2 zlib1g-dev php7.1-dev
```

then compile extension

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached.git
cd php-memcached
phpize
./configure
make
sudo mv modules/ /usr/local/memcached/
```

and then enable that in your php.ini file append at the end as

```
extension=/usr/local/memcached/memcached.so
```

then restart.

shameless plug 
I wrote a detailed blog post on memcached and php7.1 for Ubuntu/Debian https://www.computersnyou.com/5828